# CSS - dynamic height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to build an on-click flip card with dynamic height depending on the elements inside of it.  Right now, I have a height explicitly set to 250px, but ideally I would like the size to be dynamic.  Is this possible?

I've tried setting height to 100%, but that obviously didn't work.  I also tried making  a flexbox, but that doesn't seem to work either. Additionally, I also tried using min-height=250px...not sure why that doesn't work either.  Any lessons on how to correctly determine the CSS is greatly appreciated!

Here's my HTML and CSS:

```css
label {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
 height: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms;
  transition: all 600ms;
  z-index: 20;
}

.card div, .card span {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center; 
}

.card div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.card .back {
  background: $color-lightest;
  color: $color-darkest;
  border: 1px solid $color-darkest;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

input {
  display: none;
}

:checked + .card {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.icon-color, .icon-background {
  color: $color-accent-light;
}

.front.icon-color {
  z-index:100;
}

.card .front, .card .back {
  padding:1.5em;
}

.card .front {
  background: $color-darkest;  
}

.title{
  text-align:center;
  color: $color-lightest;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
        <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-1x icon-color" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
      <h2 class="title">My Information</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <h3>Header</h3>
      <h5>Subheader</h5>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible.

`height: auto;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height

So long as you have a hard-coded value of 250px, it will not be possible.

Comment: Thanks @hcs, I tried setting height: auto; on <label> but it shrinks almost completely

Answer (score 0):

Just letting the browser calculate the height should work. So dont specify a height. But I also had to translate your card to show it where its supposed to be after a 180 rotation. So maybe that's your problem?

```css
label {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms;
  transition: all 600ms;
  z-index: 20;
}

.card div, .card span {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center; 
}

.card div {
  position: absolute;
  //height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.card .back {
  background: wheat;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateY(100%); // translate missing?
  transform: rotateX(180deg) translateY(100%); // translate missing?
}

input {
  display: none;
}

:checked + .card {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.icon-color, .icon-background {
  color: $color-accent-light;
}

.front.icon-color {
  z-index:100;
}

.card .front, .card .back {
  padding:1.5em;
}

.card .front {
  background: $color-darkest;  
}

.title{
  text-align:center;
  color: $color-lightest;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
        <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-1x icon-color" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
      <h2 class="title">My Information</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <h3>Header</h3>
      <h5>Subheader</h5>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon the issue is the hardcoded height, but ALSO, the absolute positioning. Just commenting out those helps.

```css
label {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
/*  height: 250px; */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms;
  transition: all 600ms;
  z-index: 20;
}

.card div, .card span {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center; 
}

.card div {
 /*  position: absolute; */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.card .back {
  background: $color-lightest;
  color: $color-darkest;
  border: 1px solid $color-darkest;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

input {
  display: none;
}

:checked + .card {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.icon-color, .icon-background {
  color: $color-accent-light;
}

.front.icon-color {
  z-index:100;
}

.card .front, .card .back {
  padding:1.5em;
}

.card .front {
  background: $color-darkest;  
}

.title{
  text-align:center;
  color: $color-lightest;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
        <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-1x icon-color" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
      <h2 class="title">My Information</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <h3>Header</h3>
      <h5>Subheader</h5>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Info</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
```